# Name lookup of friend function in local class

Tags: c++, name-lookup

Compiling the following:

```
void bar() { /* ... */ }

void foo()
{
    struct MyStruct
    {
        friend void bar();
    };
}

int main()
{
    //..
}
```

results in the error:

> error: friend declaration 'void bar()' in local class without prior declaration

Why does name lookup fail? How can I fix it?

Comment: When dealing with an error, it's a good idea to post the exact error message. It helps others with the same problem find your question.

Comment: `error: friend declaration 'void bar()' in local class without prior declaration.`

Comment: Please update the question with the error message. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a QA & site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a local class out of its enclosing scope even if you friend things becuase `The name of a local class is local to its enclosing scope` - §9.8/1.

---

However if you just want to get it to compile, explicitly tell it it look in global scope...

```
friend void ::bar();
```

*This fixes it in VS but not in GCC for some reason

§11.3/11 (thanks jrok)

> If a friend declaration appears in a local class (9.8) and the name specified is an unqualified name, a prior
>   declaration is looked up without considering scopes that are outside the innermost enclosing non-class scope.

Comment: This was my thought too, but it fails with the same error (GCC 4.6.1)

Comment: It fixes it in VS2010; the original warning in VS2010 was: `warning C4813: 'bar' : a friend function of a local class must have been previously declared`

Comment: §9.8/1 also says: _Declarations in a local class can use only type names, static variables, extern variables and functions, and enumerators from the enclosing scope._  I'm still not sure if `::bar()` is correct.